# Access Firefox from C#

Tags: c#, firefox

Scenario is simple:

If you add a web browser in visual studio it adds IE. If you are logged somewhere with IE it keeps you authenticated like reading cookies or sessions. Web browser component and IE is the same.

So, is there a way to access firefox from c# (like web browser or some way) and lets say load a page and get the html of this page? Or load a page, fill a textbox and click a button, all these via c#?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Please edit your question to clear that up.  That might make it more obvious to us what the correct answer is.  You talk both about automating web pages, and using a browser control in a GUI application you are writing.  Those two things don't entirely mix in my mind, so your question is confusing to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) is a browser automation framework that will let you perform these tasks using C#.  There's a [driver for Firefox](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriver) that works very well.

Comment: The problem is that with Selenium creates a new instance of firefox but it snot shares cookies and sessions from the user installed version of firefox. I want to integrate firefox on c# to get data from an authenticated user via the dom.

Comment: You can solve that too with Selenium.  I'm stuck without power in the NorthEast USA otherwise I'd look it up.  It used to require creating a FireFoxProfle or FireFoxProfileManager object and choosing which profile you want to operate the browser as.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way of using Firefox from within C# by default. You do have a few options however,  if you want to do something with it's rendering engine for example you could use [GeckoFX](http://code.google.com/p/geckofx/) to give yourself a nice C# wrapped GECKO engine.

If it involves testing / automation then you could look into [WatiN](http://watin.org/) which supports various browsers or even [UI automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa348551.aspx).